# How to input extracted data from excel into a website using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, automation

Task: Automatically pull up a specific website, navigate to inventory module, once in inventory input SKU, QTY per box, and QTY of boxes, click enter and a label is printed.

I've gotten to the point where I can navigate through the website using selenium `webdriver` and get to my inventory menu.

In addition, I've extracted the data from excel into python using pandas.

However, I'm having trouble understanding how I would input the extracted data into the correct data fields.

Navigating the fields is not the problem. `Input` the extracted data is my issue. I've used the `actionkeys` and `sendkeys` tools to enter password,username, click tab etc.

But, how would I tell python to send a data cell from the extracted excel without typing it out in the `sendkeys` statement. Would I have to create a variable ? If so, any links or references that I could look up ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time 
import pandas as pd

#Importing Excel data into the terminal for WIP Labels
wips = pd.read_excel('/Users/juliobermudez/desktop/WipExample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
sku = wips[0:1, 1]
print(sku)

#Are these elements? I don't know.
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/juliobermudez/desktop/WIP/chromedriver')
keyboard = Controller ()

#Pull up the Plex Website
browser.get(insert website here)

#Log in into Plex using username and passoword
username = browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserID')
username.send_keys('username')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
password.send_keys('password')
company = browser.find_element_by_id('txtCompanyCode')
company.send_keys('company name')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
elem.click()

#Wait 3 Secs
time.sleep(3)

#Navigate to the Add Inventory Module
keyboard.press('2')
keyboard.release('2')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('1')
keyboard.release('1')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('5')
keyboard.release('5')

#Begin the Automation of WIPs !
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
```

Comment: Please share link/html and post your code as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @0m3r code posted, let me know if you have any hints or links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to pass a reference to dataframe cells via the sendkeys method. It looks like SKU is 2 rows and 1 column?

```
object.send_keys(sku.iat[0,1])
```

df.iat allows you to get the exact contents of a cell by index

Comment: in the code above the "object" would have to be equal to the specific web element where the data is going to be entered, correct ? problem is that the website i will be using does not let me inspect, it is blocked by the administrator. thanks for the hit on the df.iat command. what i'm using right now is using keyboard controller to navigate to the specific field where i need enter the data. i think that i will use the controller and utilize the keyboard.type command to enter the sku.iat?

Comment: Yeah object is the element you're targeting. I don't know about Pynput. So when you try to use keyboard.press(), you might need to set up a for loop to be able to enter the contents of the cell.  Again, I don't know if pynput supports passing entire strings or if it's one character at a time